# USing AddExpression / MathExpression in Weka

Tags: filter, attributes, preprocessor, weka

I am working on a very basic WEKA assignment, and I'm trying to use WEKA to preprocess data from the GUI (most current version). I am trying to do very basic if statements and mathematical statements in the expression box when double clicking on MathExpression and I haven't had any success. For example I want to do

```
if (a5 == 2 || a5 == 0) then y = 1; else y = 0
```

Many different variations of this haven't worked for me and I'm also unclear on how to refer to "y" or if it needs a reference within the line.

Another example is  -abs(log(a7)–3) which I wasn't able to work out either. Any ideas about how to make these statements work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javadoc of [MathExpression](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html)

> The 'A'
>     letter refers to the value of the attribute being processed.
>     Other attribute values (numeric only) can be accessed through
>     the variables A1, A2, A3, ...

Your filter applies to all attributes of your dataset. If I load iris dataset and apply following filter.

> weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression -E log(A).

your attribute ,sepallength values change as following.

```
Before Filter      After Filter           
Minimum 4.3    Minimum  1.459
Maximum 7.9    Maximum  2.067
Mean    5.843  Mean 1.755
StdDev  0.828  StdDev   0.141
```

Also if you look to javadoc, there is no if else function but ifelse function. Therefore you should write something like

```
ifelse ( (A == 2 || A == 0), 1,0 )
```

Also this filter applies to all attributes. If you want to change only one attribute and according to other attribute values ; then you need to use "Ignore range option" and use A1,A2 to refer to other attribute values.

if you need to add new attribute use [AddExpression](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/AddExpression.html).

> An instance filter that creates a new attribute by applying a mathematical expression to existing attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe this is correct. However, I can't manage to get MathExpression to apply to a new attribute that doesn't have values set already, so perhaps this is the problem. Any ideas about that?